# Structure for multiple files in C

Tags: c

Have this simple struct in my header file

```
struct cont
{
 char fname[10];
 char lname[10];
 char user[10];
 char pass[10];
 float price;
}s;
```

I am having this linking errors about the declaration of `struct cont s` in the header file.
By the way, I have multiple files(.C) containing the functions and the main. Files cant find the structure. Is this the correct way of declaring a global structure? So I can use it for all my files.

Comment: A `struct` defines a *data type* ; you probably want to declare (and possibly define) a *global variable*

Comment: "*I am having this linking errors*" why not share them with us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach is to

1. Define the structure in the header file.
2. Declare one `extern` variable of that structure type in the header file.
3. Define the variable in one of your `.c` files.

Comment: `extern struct cont s;` then when I want to use it on other `.c` files I put `struct cont s;` ?

Comment: @imagineracoon maybe in `main.c`, _define_ the structure, `struct cont s`. in other files, simply use `s`. The `extrn` is already there in the included header file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options I can think of, for instance you can declare this in a header file

```
struct cont
{
   char fname[10];
   char lname[10];
   char user[10];
   char pass[10];
   float price;
};
```

and then include the header file, in every .c file that needs to use the struct, and declare instances of your struct as `struct cont instanceOfCont;`

```
#include "headerfile.h"
struct cont instanceOfCont;
```

you can write functions to alter the members of the struct, and then put the definition of the struct in the file where you implement thos functions, say `cont.c`

```
struct cont
{
   char fname[10];
   char lname[10];
   char user[10];
   char pass[10];
   float price;
};

const char *contGetFirstName(struct cont *instance)
{
    if (instance == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return instance->fname;
}
.
.
.
```

/* And so on */

and then to declare an instance of the struct in another c file, you use pointers like

```
struct cont *instance;
```

finally you can `typedef` the struct too like

```
typedef struct cont Cont;
```

and then use `Cont` instead of `struct cont` to declare an instance of it.

Comment: Searching lead me to this kind of way which I don't understand clearly. Thanks